# <ul> inside <li> changes <li> width

Tags: css, html-lists

I have a menu which is a `<ul>`. Inside one of the `<li>`s I have another `<ul>` to add a depth level, a sub-menu. However, when hovering the `<li>` to make the sub-menu appear, it's width changes to match the `<ul>`s. Also, the sub-menu will pull the content area down, and that's not what I want.

I want the `<li>` to maintain it's width when it's hovered, and the sub-menu to appear on top of the content area.

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cthulhu/RWjcA/ (If you hover Products, you will see it happen.)

Comment: Why do you have three different selectors -  `#main_menu .menu ul` and a `#main_menu .sub-menu` and a `#main_menu ul ul` - for the sub-menu? That could certainly be refactored.

Comment: I'm editing an existing website. I just created a jsFiddle with a part of the code.

Comment: @Cthulhu How many levels of sub-menus are you working with?

Comment: Exactly what is demonstrated on the jsFiddle. Only one item will have one sub-menu, and that's it.

Comment: @Cthulhu In that case put all styles in the `#main_menu .sub-menu` selector. There is no reason to have three separate selectors for the same "sub-menu" class of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply give a fixed height to that Div

```
#main_menu .menu {
list-style: none outside none;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
height:60px;
}
```

Hope this will help...

Comment: That actually helps part of the problem, never thought it could be so simple. However, I still have an issue with the changing width of the `<li>`.

Comment: Oh sorry I've missed that part. 
That beacause of the width of "What When How"
this time you need to add a fixed with to #main_menu li. 
    #main_menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none outside none;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:120px;
    }

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly cleaned up version, and without the need for Javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/dZhQN/2/

#### HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>Whatever</a></li>
    <li>
        <a>Products</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>What When How</a></li>
            <li><a>Who Why</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Contacts</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="content"></div>
​
```

#### CSS

```
#nav, #nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

#nav li a {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 24px 20px 15px;
}
#nav > li > a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background: #4A6125;
}

#nav ul {
    background: #000;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: -75px;
}
#nav ul li a {
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;            
}


#content {
    background: gold;
    height: 200px;
}
​
```